# UIGraphicsBeginContext, UIGraphicsEndImageContext in Cocoa?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage

I'm porting bits of an iOS app to OSX and have this code that creates an NSImage at runtime. But I'm having trouble converting it to Cocoa for OSX. Could someone help with the Cocoa equivalents of UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext and UIGraphicsEndImageContext?

```
- (UIImage *)progressImage:(double)progress size: size {
    CGFloat height = size.height;
    CGFloat width = size.width;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Gray background
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 102.0 / 255.0, 102.0 / 255.0, 102.0 / 255.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height));

    // Orange progress
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 241.0 / 255.0, 89.0 / 255.0, 42.0 / 255.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width * (CGFloat) progress, height));

    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resultingImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Quartz 2d Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) should help.

Take a look at [NSGraphicsContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSGraphicsContext_Class/index.html) to get the basic equivalent of UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext().